# How to link multiple records at once using cakephp hasMany?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I googled this a lot but nothing seems to be similar to what i am looking for..

What i am trying to do is to link one record "User" with other multiple records "Cards" at once using a multiple HTML  list.

Tables are:
users (id, name, username)
cards (id, user_id)

Models:

```
class User extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'User';
    public $hasMany = array('Card');}

class Card extends AppModel {    
    public $name = 'Card';
    public $belongsTo = array('User');}
```

User edit.ctp view

```
echo $this->Form->input('id');
echo $this->Form->input('Card', array('multiple'=>true));
```

How my controller gonna look like? currently it looks like this but saves nothing but the User record "without the related cards"

```
if (!empty($this->data)) {
    foreach($this->data['User']['Card'] as $key => $item){
        $this->data['User']['Card'][$key] = array('id'=>$item, 'user_id'=>$this->data['User']['id']);
                        }
        if ($this->User->saveAll($this->data)) {
            //$this->User->Card->saveAll($this->data);
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved', true));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.', true));
    }
}
if (empty($this->data)) {
    $this->data = $this->User->read(null, $id);
    $this->set('cards', $this->User->Card->find('list'));
}
```

$this->data contains:

```
Array
(
    [User] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [name] => Superman
        [status] => 1
        [Card] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 11402130001
                [user_id] => 1
            )
            [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 11402130002
                [user_id] => 1
            )
            [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 11402130003
                [user_id] => 1
            )
            [3] => Array
            (
                [id] => 11402130004
                [user_id] => 1
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a user_id entry for your cards so that your data will look like something like this :

```
Array
(
    [User] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10
        )
    [Card] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                [id] => 1
                [user_id] => 10
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                [id] => 2
                [user_id] => 10
                )

        )
)
```

I would go for a foreach loop on the $this->data['Card] array :

```
foreach ($this->data['Card'] as &$card) {
  $card['user_id'] = $this->data['User']['id'];
}
```

You can then do your saveAll. Btw, the *$this->User->Card->saveAll($this->data)* should be removed.

Comment: Thanks G.J but it doesn't work! i tried this before but it ain't saving the user_id any idea what is the problem? i am using 1.3.4

Comment: @mmahgoub what if you put the Card array outside the User array ? I'm not sure it's gonna work anyway. If it doesn't, maybe you should try to change your way of doing by trying to save the Cards instead of the User. Tell me if it works.

Comment: Hi G.J actually it does work if it's like this: `if ($this->User->saveAll($this->data['User'])) {
$this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved', true));}` but comes another problem! CakePHP doesn't recognize unselected items in other words it could link cards to a User when i select them but doesn't unlink when i remove the selection! any idea how to achieve this without foreach loop and saveField and this kind of stuff?

Comment: I guess i just need to set user_id to 0 but how i can achieve that i only get selected items in Card array?!

Comment: This doesn't appears to be possible cause $_POST it self doesn't hold the unselected items, so it must be done through for loop to do the comparison.

Comment: if i understand well what you want to do, you want to set the user_id of some cards to null and the user_id of the remaining cards to the current user id. To achieve this, you could start by doing an updateAll on your Cards $this->User->Card->updateAll(array('Card.user_id' => null)); and then use the saveAll